# How can I pass data from one page to another?

Tags: php, mysql

So regarding my question I have two pages. **Page1.php** to save customer sale information and **Page2.php** to display the sales(Page2 is connected to a monitor in our office no user interaction, no keyboard, no mouse).

.

In Page1 the users can save information about customer sales. For example product name. The users user is always connected to the sale. After submitting the sale, I want it to show up on Page2., and says something like: **User Demitri just sold a PS4**.

**What have I tried so far**:

Now when the user register sale, it saves into a MySQL table, and the Page2. automatically refreshes(`<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="10"/>`) the page every 10 second to see if any new record has been added to the table. If a new record is there, it will display the user and the product that was sold on the page for 30 seconds, example: **User Demitri just sold a PS4**, and then it will remove the record from the table, and then refresh the page again to see if any new record has been added to the table.

**What do I want to accomplish:**

I want a sort of system that can be used to pass data from Page1. to Page2, without needed any user interaction on Page2, and don't need to have a auto refresh script that runs every 10 second. This also looks bad because every time it refreshes, the website will sort of blink.

This is a very cumbersome process to do it, there must be some other way?

Comment: you can use websockets

Answer (score 0):

I will recommend using a dB to store the data and the page that needs that data can query the data.. Maybe using ajax, fetch and  some setinterval function

Comment: That's almost quite the same than what OP did, but using ajax instead of refresh

Answer (score 0):

1. Use ajax, so you don't have to refresh the page every 10 seconds.
2. Use websockets. Once you notice a new sale, you just push it and then your connected page can display it. This would be the best way i think.

Comment: Could you provide an example using websockets? I have never used it before.

Comment: https://medium.com/@cn007b/super-simple-php-websocket-example-ea2cd5893575